# Replace MDL icon font hamburgeur icon with svg

Tags: javascript, svg, material-design

Partly so I don't have to wait for the entire font file to load before icon displays, and because I've been reading a bit of [discussion](https://benfrain.com/seriously-use-icon-fonts/) (pro and con) about using svg's instead of icon-fonts I am experimenting with using an svg instead of MDLs native icon font for the Material Design Lite `mdl-navigation` drawer.

On compatible browsers, they add the icon using the following script, which I don't want to modify, in case of upgrades.

```
if (this.drawer_) {
    var drawerButton = this.element_.querySelector('.' + this.CssClasses_.DRAWER_BTN);
    if (!drawerButton) {
        drawerButton = document.createElement('div');
        drawerButton.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
        drawerButton.setAttribute('role', 'button');
        drawerButton.setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
        drawerButton.classList.add(this.CssClasses_.DRAWER_BTN);
        var drawerButtonIcon = document.createElement('i');
        drawerButtonIcon.classList.add(this.CssClasses_.ICON);
        drawerButtonIcon.innerHTML = this.Constant_.MENU_ICON;
        drawerButton.appendChild(drawerButtonIcon);
    } # etc...
}
```

I came up with this:

```
var mdl_drawer_button = document.querySelector('.mdl-layout__drawer-button');
mdl_drawer_button.innerHTML = '<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="icon nav-icon"><use xlink:href="#nav-icon"></use></svg>';
```

However, `'.mdl-layout__drawer-button'` doesn't exist until the MDL script has run, so am adding a 500ms timeout as seen in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mikeill/ypoLo51t/).

Does my approach make sense? It there a more dependable way to run my function *once the MDL code has run*?

UPDATE:

Trying a slightly different method now using a recursive function with a test for `.mdl-layout__drawer-button` not being null:

```
//Replace MDL icon with our sprite
function mdl_drawer_btn() {
    var mdl_drawer_button = document.querySelector('.mdl-layout__drawer-button');
    if (mdl_drawer_button != null) {
        mdl_drawer_button.innerHTML = '<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="icon nav-icon"><use xlink:href="#nav-icon"></use></svg>';
      } else {
        setTimeout(mdl_drawer_btn, 100);
      }
  }

setTimeout(mdl_drawer_btn, 100);
```

Comment: Further discussion: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1014

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to advise without knowing how your whole site is implemented, but I would have thought it should be enough to put your script as the last script on the page.  Then to make sure all DOM changes, that previous scripts have made, are complete, wrap it in a 0ms timeout.

```
setTimeout(mdl_drawer_btn, 0);
```

Comment: Even with this code as the last line before the `</body>` tag, `document.querySelector('.mdl-layout__drawer-button')` is `null`.